# Can we change float value when resize window screen

Tags: html, css, css-float

Earlier float value was right, So when i re-size window screen then float value should become like none.How can i do?

```
<style>
#test{
float:right;
padding: 10px;
color:"blue";

}
</style>
```

Then after i tried with this code but its not working

```
<style>
@media all and (min-width: 450px){
 float:none;
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place the css rule within the same `#test` class.

```
<style>
@media all and (min-width: 450px){
   #test {
    float:none;
   }
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `css selector`,

Try:

```
@media all and (min-width: 450px){
    #test{float:none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.m

```
<style>
@media all and (max-width: 450px) {
  #test {
   float:none;
  }
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First as all the other answers pointed out you have to do this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 450px){
    #test{float:none}
}
```

But you pointed out that it's not working, my guess would be that you added the default properties for #test after you media-query. The selector that you wrote outside a media query is always "available", and it overwrites your property. Adding `!important` should fix that.

```
@media all and (min-width: 450px){
    #test{float:none !important}
}
```